# SharePoint online Search returning multiple site collection results

Tags: sharepoint-online

> Hi ,
>   I want to restrict search of Sharepoint results to just one site collection.
>   For this i created a new result source and tried the following queries
>   {?{searchTerms} SPSiteURL={SiteCollection.URL}}
>   {?{searchTerms} -contentClass:STS_Site  Path={SiteCollection.URL}*}

Tried the Path in text string too but doesn't work .
In fact if i use Path it doesn't bring any results back. 
I understand it doesn't need full crawl . is this correct ? where am i going wrong

Answer (score 1):

**Please try the below query to get search results ,Related to what we are typing on searchbox.**

- path:URL {SearchBoxQuery}*

OR

- SPSiteURL:URL {SearchBoxQuery}*

Eg:

1. path:https://test.com/sites/test {SearchBoxQuery}*
2. SPSiteURL:https://test.com/sites/test {SearchBoxQuery}*

**If you need to filter by a particular text.**

- path:URL welcome*

OR

- SPSiteURL:URL test*

Eg:

1. path:https://test.com/sites/test welcome*
2. SPSiteURL:https://test.com/sites/test test*

**For multiple site collections**

```js
path:https://test.com/sites/test1 OR path:https://test.com/sites/test2 {SearchBoxQuery}*
```

OR

```js
path:https://test.com/sites/test1 OR path:https://test.com/sites/test2 welcome*
```

Comment: thank you @sreeraj . is this to be added in the custom result source ? because that's not working.

Comment: 1)If have created a custom Webpart.xml file ,in the xml code you can add the above query as "QueryTemplate".
2)Or you can add this in the custom result source